# UIView in a MapView disappears

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mapkit

I have a problem with google maps in ios. I have a screen with the MapView and I am drawing some annotations (polygones dispalying zones on the streets). If somebody taps the zone it gets selected a button shows up and the user can press it to start a transaction. He has to hold the button for 2s and in this time a small view with a progress bar is shown to indicate that the user has to hold it till it comes to end. This works fine. However sometimes after playing a bit following problem appears:

The View with the progress bar show up but disappears before it reaches the end. If try next time everything works smoothly. Here is the code that matters, I think:

```
- (IBAction)starButtonTouched:(id)sender {
    self.progressLabel.text = [NSLocalizedString(@"Please hold", nil) uppercaseString];
    if (!self.currentVehicle) return;
    self.progressBar.hidden = NO;
    self.progressBarBackground.hidden = NO;
    self.progressBar.progress = 0;
    [self performSelector:@selector(_updateProgress) withObject:nil afterDelay:kVTMainButtonPressDuration/kVTMainProgressSteps];
}

- (IBAction)startButtonReleased:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"StartButton released - progress bar will be hidden");
    self.progressBar.hidden = YES;
    self.progressBarBackground.hidden = YES;
}

- (void) _updateProgress {

    if (self.progressBar.hidden) return;

   /*
    * update progress bar
    */
   float actual = [self.progressBar progress];
   if (actual < 1) {

       self.progressBar.progress += 1.0/kVTMainProgressSteps;
       [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kVTMainButtonPressDuration/kVTMainProgressSteps target:self 
                                   selector:@selector(_updateProgress) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];

   /*
    * if it has ended start the transaction
    */
   } else {

       ASLogInfo(@"Starting");
       if (!self.currentVehicle) return;

       [self.service startParking:self.currentVehicle zone:self.selectedZone callback:^(VTTransaction *transaction) {
        [self loadCurrentTransaction];
       }];

   }

}
```

Does anybody have an idea what and why causes the View to disappear? Thanks a lot.

Bye,
Filip

Comment: is startButtonReleased called in this unexpected case?

Comment: No it isn't. That is really weird.